# Monitoring subdirectories on a network drive with python watchdog module

Tags: python, directory, ftp, watchdog, python-watchdog

I'm using this code to monitor the creation of new files in a directory in my network drive and having issues, when I test the same code on a directory in the local drive it has no issues. When a new file is created in the directory it triggers the event and sends a message to the console, if a file is created in a subdirectory of that it also triggers an event and sends a message.

But when I change the path back to the directory in the network drive, if the schedule has recursion=True than no events are triggered in the directory or subdirectory, if recursion=False events are only triggered in the scheduled directory.

The end goal for this is to constantly monitor the network drive and anytime a new file is uploaded to a subdirectory of the directory being watched it'll send the file to the corresponding directory of another drive via FTP. Please let me know if there is an issue I'm missing with Watchdog or if there is a better way to accomplish my goal.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
from pathlib import Path

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
def on_created(self, event):
    path1=Path(event.src_path)
    parpath=path1.parent
    print("New file created in " + str(parpath))
    return super().on_created(event)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
path = /network/drive

event_handler = MyEventHandler()
observer = PollingObserver()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that! In the main directory on a network drive it detects events but in a subdir does not. And it works well in subdirs in the local filesystem.